# Filter outgoing html files

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I have custom syntax in all `*.html` files which need to be filtered by `filter.php` before being served. I am assuming that this can be done with `.htaccess`.

Note, I do not wish to parse `*.html` as PHP.

[image: example]

Comment: why not use a template engine such as smarty. Building your own parser can be rather difficult

Comment: It's a long story. But all I can use is .htaccess and a .php file

Comment: Are you asking about a trivial RewriteRule for redirecting *.html files through a script? What's your difficulty there then? There are awfully many examples on SO.

Comment: @mario that's not constructive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your htaccess, add

```
RewriteRule (.*\.html) filter.php?htmlfile=$1
```

Now, in filter.php, you can

```
$html = file_get_contents($_GET['htmlfile']);
// and do whatever you need to do
// then
echo $html;
```

Answer (score 0):

in ur htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.+)\.html$ controller.php?file=$1 [NC,L]
```

in ur php file u can have

```
if(isset($_GET["file"])
{
file logic ......
redirect code
}
```

Comment: for some reason it's not sending *.html files to controller.php

Comment: I'm sorry, made a mistake in a hurry. Should work just fine now. The rewrite conditions will make sure that an existing file or directory will not be included in this rewrite case.]

Comment: *.html are existing files, so excluding existing files won't work. Also, it's passing the file name to the controller, without the *.html extension, so the controller doesn't know the full file name to Get. But I did get it all figured out, thanks!